# MSI GS65 Stealth Thin 8RE less than symbol printing ç symbol

Tags: keyboard, 19.04, msi

In Ubuntu 18.04 the keyboard worked very nicely. I selected either the "Spanish (Spain)" or "Catalan (Spain, L with dot)" and every key was fine. Even the less-than and great-than symbols, which for this laptop, the key is between the SPACE BAR and the ALT-GR keys.

However, after installing from zero (not updating) the Ubuntu 19.04, the less-than and great-than symbols aren't working. They display the ç and Ç symbols whey I press them.

I have been searching around but haven't really found anything that seems to help.

If someone can help, would be lovely! It's awful not being able to code without these symbols :(

Comment: Installing later versions of Ubuntu solved the issue for good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***WorkAround***

from the outputs you provided, both the physical keys are with same keycodes, thus changing the keysymbols for each key will result in same keysymbol.

> This is the output I get when typing any of the physical keys < or ç

```
$ xev | grep keycode
    state 0x2000, keycode 51 (keysym 0xe7, ccedilla), same_screen YES,
    state 0x2000, keycode 51 (keysym 0xe7, ccedilla), same_screen YES,
$ xev | grep keycode
    state 0x2000, keycode 51 (keysym 0xe7, ccedilla), same_screen YES,
    state 0x2000, keycode 51 (keysym 0xe7, ccedilla), same_screen YES,
```

[image: Hi]

So we need to assign different keycode to any of the physical keys <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>ç</kbd>

1. So decide which physical key keycode to be changed first out of the two.
2. run `xmodmap -pke` and choose any empty keycode

example:

```
keycode 245 = XF86Bluetooth NoSymbol XF86Bluetooth NoSymbol XF86Bluetooth
keycode 246 = XF86WLAN NoSymbol XF86WLAN NoSymbol XF86WLAN
keycode 247 =
keycode 248 =
keycode 249 =
keycode 250 =
keycode 251 =
keycode 252 =
keycode 253 =
keycode 254 = XF86WWAN NoSymbol XF86WWAN NoSymbol XF86WWAN
keycode 255 = XF86RFKill NoSymbol XF86RFKill NoSymbol XF86RFKill
```

I will choose 248 here.. now the trick is to deduct 8 from xmodmap keycode to use with `setkeycodes` which is 248-8=240

Refer to `man setkeycodes` and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52949

3. logon to any tty and run `showkey --scancodes` press the key and grab the scan code. in my case it is 0x2b but only `2b` to be considered.

Refer to `man showkey`

[image]

4. run `sudo setkeycodes 2b 240` this means when we run xmodmap the physical key which we selected shows keycode of 248
5. change to Desktop from tty

check with `xev | grep keycode` and press the physical key.

Example:

```
pratap@pratap:~$ xev | grep keycode
    state 0x10, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248
    state 0x10, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    state 0x10, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
pratap@pratap:~$ xmodmap -e "keycode 248 = ccedilla Ccedilla"
pratap@pratap:~$ çççççççççççççç
```

6. Now both the physcial keys have different keycodes which you can map to any keysym you want.. lets say keycode 51 and keycode 248

run below commands:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 51 = less greater"
xmodmap -e "keycode 248 = ccedilla Ccedilla"
```

7. All the changes will not stay after a reboot.., So xmodmap commands you can keep in startupapplications preferences and please follow the link provided https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52949 for `setkeycodes` command.

Note: Tested in Ubuntu 19.04 but not with the keyboard type in the Question.