# Mark accents not working on Ubuntu 19.04 and an MSI GS65 Stealth Thin 8RE

Tags: keyboard-layout

A few days ago, I opened an issue (that is still unaswered and might be related [MSI GS65 Stealth Thin 8RE less than symbol printing ç symbol](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175072/msi-gs65-stealth-thin-8re-less-than-symbol-printing-%c3%a7-symbol) ) about the keyboard of my MSI laptop and the less-than < and great-than symbols > not working on it.

Sadly, I haven't figured out yet a way to resolve this. But just today, I've realized that the mark accents aren't working either.

Every time I press on the ´ or ` symbols, they get written immediately, without giving me the chance of pressing a vowel to write the acute versions of these vowels, I get the following:

- ´a
- ´e
- ´i
- ´o
- ´u

There's definitely something wrong with my keyboard and the thing is that it worked perfectly fine after installing Ubuntu 18.04. But after I did a clean install of 19.04 I'm getting this keyboard problems.

Any help would be really appreciated :(

Comment: Not really, it has Spanish layout. I've tried setting it up to en-US or other layouts without any luck.

Comment: Only if I set it up to Spanish, then the ç works great. Which is necessary for Catalan language and it's on Spanish layout.

Comment: So right now the only thing, as far as you know, is to perform a temporary remap and wait for the definitive fix. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99289/discussion-between-xarlymg89-and-pratap).

Comment: Confirmed that except the less-than and great-than symbols, the mark accents are working fine on Ubuntu 19.04 live CD.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Just sent you the content of both files through the chat. But here they are. Ubuntu 19.04: https://gist.github.com/carlos-mg89/a3ef1bd71f277edd5783271796c4b466 and for Ubuntu 19.04 Live CD: https://gist.github.com/carlos-mg89/727244c4e73caab718f8c73d8ea3a745

Comment: I've just posted the solution @PRATAP Thank you for helping and for bringing back to my mind that I had actually made a change to try to fix my other keyboard layout issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I've got to fix the keyboard layout about the mark accents matter at least.

I had applied a change in the ~/.profile file:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
export XMODIFIERS=@im=xim
```

However, the previous values were:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
```

I remember changing those values to try to fix the problem I still have with the less-than and great-than symbols not being printed as described in [MSI GS65 Stealth Thin 8RE less than symbol printing ç symbol](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175072/msi-gs65-stealth-thin-8re-less-than-symbol-printing-%c3%a7-symbol)

So one problem solved, after messing things up ¬¬

Comment: If you still have a remote idea about what's the matter with my other problem, will appreciate it :)