# Rekey special Keys on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lenovo, keyboard-layout

I found here in askubuntu some tutorials how to rekey keyboard keys. That seems to be good for most keys. However in my Lenovo Ideapad 330 I have a side keyboard with keys such as back track and next track.

Also, I have the Home and End button fabric coded with the Fn key.
If I want to go to the end of the line I have to click Fn + Right arrow.

I want to re-key the back and next track keys so that they will have the function of the Home and End buttons.

The problem is that with those specific buttons in `xev` I don't see any ID for those keys. Here is what I get if I press back track:

```
FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyPointer

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   32  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer
```

Can anyone suggest how to re-code such two keys?

[Here](https://www.lenovo.com/medias/lenovo-laptop-ideapad-330-15-gallery-03.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8OTk3NTd8aW1hZ2UvanBnfGg5NS9oNDYvOTcxNDY5OTg5NDgxNC5qcGd8YmMxMWIwZjZhZDgzZjQyOWZlMTE2NWYyOWM3OGRlZGQzNDk4MWJhNWVjYmI3MDgzZWRkNjVhZTA3MWUxMDIxYw) is a photo of the keyboard.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: hmm, thanks for the hint. I tried in Videos and Rythmbox and these keys do nothing. Do you think it can be a hardware problem, or something else I can change?

Comment: sorry, I forgot. I just added a link to a photo of the keyboard in the original question

Comment: yes I will be here, but probably I can't reply immediately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99677/discussion-between-pikk-and-pratap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some media keys like this below pic, may produce the keycode or may not.. and they may function while you press it under `xev` command..

[image]

so the easy way to get the keycode of these keys is to logon to tty and run `showkey -k` and press the required key..

Here based on the chat.. the keycodes when `showkey -k` command is used in tty are 163 for Previous Track and 165 for Next Track

> also the next/previous track give keycode 165 and 163

Sorry there is no Documentation for below:

```
keycode with showkey -k = xmodmap keycode - 8
keycode with xmodmap = showkey -k + 8
```

this means the keycodes we got with showkey -k 163 and 165 are equivalent to 171 and 173 with xmodmap

thus.. run `xmodmap -pke` and look for the keysymbols for keycodes 171 and 173..

later you can change whatever keysym you want to map.
for example:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 171 = Home"
xmodmap -e "keycode 173 = End"
```

---

Further Reading:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1177739/739431
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52949

---

> keycode 171 = XF86AudioNext NoSymbol XF86AudioNext
>   keycode 173 = XF86AudioPrev NoSymbol XF86AudioPrev

Based on above unmodified keysym for the keycodes, you can run these below commands at every boot or simply add those to startup applications preferences

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 171 = Home XF86AudioPrev"
xmodmap -e "keycode 173 = End XF86AudioNext"
```

this means pressing the key alone gives Home/ End and pressing the key along with Shift modifier give track previous/ track next

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99812/discussion-on-answer-by-pratap-rekey-special-keys-on-ubuntu-18-04).