# Disable keyboard lock key

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, lock-screen, xev

My keyboard has a LockScreen key positioned where I often inadvertently hit it. I want to disable or remap that button.

I have looked in

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`

and in

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`

but don't see anything in either file that is clearly mapped to locking the display.

`xev`

spits out many lines that are immediately obscured by the lock screen, and then further obscured by all the input required to unlock the lock screen.

**After comment from @UnKNOWn**

```
 xmodmap -pke | grep keycode and then from the list try to see anything related to lock? – UnKNOWn 53 mins ago
```

Looking at the xmodmap output from the lockkey press I notice `Super_L NoSymbol Super_L map`. Super_L is another key press to lock the screen.

From the spew of output I notice this :

```
 KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x7a00001,
     root 0x26e, subw 0x0, time 518379537, (580,793), root:(582,908),
     state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
     XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As if the special Lock key on this keyboard activates the process mapped to Super_L

what's going on?

Comment: can you try `xmodmap -pke | grep keycode` and then from the list try to see anything related to lock?

Comment: Try from tty black screen https://askubuntu.com/a/1177739/739431

Comment: @UnKNOWn Ah! Nice trick. Looks like the keycode is 38. (0x26)

Comment: @UnKNOWn Only caps lock and scroll lock. There is `Super_L NoSymbol Super_L` which in  mapped from 133 which also locks the screen. Interesting to note some output from xev which I have added to the question – Stephen Boston